# rubymine throws error as argument error invalid date in strptime

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

When I pass a date mm-dd-yyyy in a variable in strptime in rubymine feature, it throws error.
query =  04-11-1998
Then(/^I see (.*) on the form$/) do |query|
mdate1 = Date.strptime(query,"%m-%d-%Y")
puts "parsing output1 is #{mdate1}"

mdate2 = DateTime.parse(mdate1).strftime("%a %b %d %Y 00:00:00 GMT+0000")
Argument Error: invalid date in strptime.
If run the separate ruby file just mdate1 = Date.strptime(query,"%m-%d-%Y") and print it, it working fine
Pls let know how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a cucumber issue it's a ruby / coding issue.

It's likely that because you're using different object classes that's where your conflict is coming from.

Comment: I am new to coding, do i have to use single variable only? Basically i input in mm-dd-yy or mm/dd/yy and i want to format to Sun Aug 20 2020 like this. Due to this, I convert in strptime then i am using strftime. Please suggest.

Comment: You are trying to co-erce something it is not liking.

Date and DateTime are different object classes. As such have different properties. You need to ensure that you pass the objects into each others parsing functions, not strings.